# apply ::after on all element of the same class

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to display a line after each element of a class. I want the line to appear for each author element but the after refer to the first element only.

Here is one item, I want a line following after each element author, currently all `::after`s refer to the same element:

```css
.youtube-author:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 342px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #1e4671;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-video-item">
  <div class="youtube-img-next" onclick="replaceVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrBLYLFl_VE')"> <img height="80" width="120" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JrBLYLFl_VE/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
  <div class="youtube-title" onclick="replaceVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrBLYLFl_VE')">Breizh Storming. Les noms de famille (1)</div>
  <div class="youtube-author">Author</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no [mcve] - We need to see the HTML as well. Show us how the CSS renders - is it showing the same way as intended?

Comment: That should work...

Comment: Add `position: relative` to `.youtube-author`.

Comment: I am using sass, that's why i have this syntax

Comment: Check the previous comment. I do understand it's SASS.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm removing unnecessary duplication of the code (among other edits)

Comment: @TylerH We need to preserve the original SASS code.

Comment: @J.Doe Check out my answer... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I didn't change any code; after you put the existing code in a snippet I removed the non-snippet pieces because it was just a repeat of the same stuff.

Comment: @TylerH It's not repeating. That was SASS code and what I wrote was CSS code. Check it out. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I see. However after looking at the question there is absolutely no Sass code in the question, so there's no need to preserve the original code bit; it shouldn't even be tagged Sass. This is an issue with CSS :-) I've edited the question again w/ a detailed edit description.

Comment: This is working Praveen, thank you!

Comment: @J.Doe You are welcome...

Comment: @TylerH Perfect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `position: relative` in your `youtube-author` class. You have to add them in the parent element (the real element) to attach the pseudo element to it, else it goes to the relatively positioned parent:

```css
.youtube-author {
  position: relative;
}

.youtube-author:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 342px;
  right: 0;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #1e4671;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-video-item">
  <div class="youtube-img-next" onclick="replaceVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrBLYLFl_VE')"> <img height="80" width="120" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JrBLYLFl_VE/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
  <div class="youtube-title" onclick="replaceVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrBLYLFl_VE')">Breizh Storming. Les noms de famille (1)</div>
  <div class="youtube-author">Author</div>
</div>
```